# Why is nav bar being pushed down with the first p element? The nav is in a separate vue components

Tags: javascript, css

So the nav is also coming down with the p element even though the styling is just on the p element only.

I would like the nav to stay at the top with the first p element having a margin.

So I've redone this answer so it's just normal.

So this is my css for nav

```
.nav {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px -20px #755f75;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li class="nav"> Home </li>
<li class="nav"> Test </li>
</ul>
</div>
<p style="margin-top: 30px"> test </p>
```

I can't add individual styling to each list item as they are in a for-loop. Any styling on one list item gets added to another.

Comment: This is almost certainly a css issue (possibly a [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) thing), but you haven't provided enough information to solve it. What does the markup and css look like for the nav in the rendered page? What's it's relationship to the adjacent content? Vue code isn't needed for this.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have the styling of the nav in the styleNavLi json. When the nav width is small I do change the display to 'inline-grid' but otherwise it is flex. I will update my answer with more code

Comment: @rayhatfield thanks again for commenting! I updated my answer. You've definitely helped me narrow it down to the nav styling and not the vue code.

Comment: You're still showing Vue/templating code. What does the _rendered html and css_ look like? Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: @rayhatfield Hi Ray I redid it. I've been really stuck on this, I assumed it would be okay as they're in separate divs.

Comment: The code you provided still doesn't reproduce the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230392/discussion-between-somebodyhelpme-and-ray-hatfield).